# How to Keep User From leaving Program in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm writing a full-screen program for children (using C# and WinForms), and it is important that they (the users) are not able to move the mouse around and end up in another program in Windows or on the desktop -- in other words, once the teacher puts this program on the screen, the children must remain there, and the teacher can only exit the program using a password).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This mode of application is called 'kiosk mode'. That alone may help your googling. You want to intercept the keystrokes that cause window switching and prevent them. You also want a fullscreen size borderless window.

Comment: Your plan is flawed if they have access to the power button, you can handle the on closing method of the form

Comment: With Windows 8 it's even more complex than before, because before if the user didn't have a keyboard but only a mouse, it was easy to stop him... Now with the "hot" corners it's more difficult. And stopping a user with a full keyboard was very very difficult

Comment: Apparently, Windows 8.1 is introducing a kiosk mode which does this (but only for TIFKAM applications, not general WinForms)

Comment: The most difficult thing is disable `Alt + TAB`, I think this can be disabled using hook but not easy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps

1. Remove borders from your application
2. Give a custom close button and On closing prompt for password
3. intercept keyboard events so that user cannot switch to other window.

Comment: This is just about software, what about hardware? The OP should prepare some cap to cover the `Power` button so that the kids can't try holding down it.

Comment: If they have access to the Hardware there is no point in doing this anyway ...

Comment: the issue that OP wants to address is not the switching off the system rather he wants that nothing else is accessible.

Comment: "are not able to move the mouse around and end up in another program in Windows or on the desktop" is the problem statement

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know of is if you handle all the default WindowMessages and supply an alternative behavior.

You probably have to change the MessageLoop for this:

[Implementing a Win32 message loop and creating a Window object with P/Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980873/implementing-a-win32-message-loop-and-creating-window-object-with-p-invoke)

This might be a lot easier in another programming language, c++ for example.